# Automatically List Dependencies For a Project

Tags: haskell, cabal

Given a Haskell project, is there a way to automatically calculate the entire list of dependencies? All the libraries it depends on as well as libraries that have been included but are not required.

Comment: Cabal does try to figure out the dependencies when you run `cabal init`.  Is that the sort of functionality you were thinking of?

Comment: At what stage? I used cabal init and it didn't figure out any dependencies.

Comment: What stage?  The stage where you've written some code and are ready to cabalize your project (create a .cabal file).  A sufficiently new version of cabal will read the modules and try to infer the dependencies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said in the comments, cabal-install already does this (I'm using cabal-install 0.14.0) by guessing the packages via module lookup (like GHCi).  It doesn't have any real intelligence w.r.t. versions so it just sets the version to the match major version of what you have installed.

Below you can see me making a dummy package that imports `Data.Vector` and cabal-install infers I am using vector 0.9.*.

```
[tommd@mavlo blah]$ pwd
/tmp/blah
[tommd@mavlo blah]$ cat Data/Blah.hs 
module Data.Blah where

import Data.Vector
[tommd@mavlo blah]$ cabal init
Package name? [default: blah] 
...SNIP...
What does the package build:
   1) Library
   2) Executable
Your choice? 1
Include documentation on what each field means (y/n)? [default: n] 

Guessing dependencies...           <--- SEE, SEE! YAY!

Generating LICENSE...
Warning: unknown license type, you must put a copy in LICENSE yourself.
Generating Setup.hs...
Generating blah.cabal...

You may want to edit the .cabal file and add a Description field.
[tommd@mavlo blah]$ cat blah.cabal 
-- Initial blah.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further documentation, 
-- see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                blah
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            Sisponys
-- description:         
-- license:             
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Me
maintainer:          No@No.No
-- copyright:           
-- category:            
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.8

library
  exposed-modules:     Data.Blah
  -- other-modules:       
  build-depends:       base ==4.5.*, vector ==0.9.*    <-- SEE?? SEE! YIPPEE!!
```

Comment: I'm using `cabal-install version 0.10.2`. That's the version that gets bundled in with the Haskell platform, so I guess this is recent functionality.

Comment: @VladtheImpala I'd guess you need the latest 0.14.0 release. It includes various `cabal init` improvements.